# How to fix the spacing before starred commands from physics package

Tags: spacing, physics

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
    \fboxsep=0pt
    This is some \fbox{$\ev*{\hat{O}_P}$} and then some.
\end{document}
```

[image]

There seems to be extra spacing added before the left angle bracket as opposed to the space after the right angle bracket when using `\ev*`. 
Is there anything I can do to fix it if I want to continue using this command from the `physics` package?

By fix, I mean I want the spacing of the right angle bracket on both sides.

Edit: I realized it does not happen with the non-starred version of the command, `\ev{\hat{O}_P}` gives the correct spacing on both sides. And that the problem seems to carry over to other starred commands like `\ket*{x}` and `\bra*{x}` where additional space is added to the left of the output.

Comment: Do you also get lots of warnings? If you do `This is some \fbox{$\langle\hat{O}_P\rangle$} and then some.`, the spacing will be equal.

Comment: @marmot No, do you? I know, but it's a hassle to write that, I'ld prefer to continue using hte `ev` command. I'm hoping for some patch I could implement to the command.

Comment: Yes, I do. Meanwhile you got an answer, which suggests not to use the package. You may just load the `braket` package and try `\fbox{$\braket{\hat{O}_P}$}`.

Answer (score 9):

I looked at the definition of `\ev` in the `physics` package.  In your case it essentially reduces to

```
\vphantom{\hat{O}_P}\left\langle\smash{\hat{O}_P}\right\rangle
```

The `\vphantom{\hat{O}_P}` will insert a box of zero width and of type mathord, but when followed by a mathopen atom (which `\left` makes automatically), spacing is inserted.

The definition of `\ev` makes absolutely no sense.  The implementers are trying to reverse the effect of the automatic scaling of `\left` and `\right` by using `\smash` to hide the height of the content, but then the construct will have no height and depth, so they reinserted using `\vphantom`.

The package code is also full of spurious spaces.  Considering the quality of the implementation, the best way to fix this issue is by **not using** the `physics` package.

Comment: As a complement to this answer, you should have a look at these posts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471532/alternatives-to-the-physics-package and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471563/physics-replacement-effort

Comment: May the downvoter please explain where this answer is lacking?

Comment: Maybe it's the `physics`'s author :)