# Hyperref interfering with custom macro

Tags: hyperref

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\d}{\text{d}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

$\d x$

$\text{d} x$

\end{document}
```

If `hyperref` is loaded after the redefinition of `\d`, then the first expression is rendered as  an upright `x` with a dot below, just as if the macro had not been redefined. Additionally, I get the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \d invalid in math mode on input line 12.
```

On the other hand, if I do not load `hyperref` or load it *before* the redefinition of `\d`, everything works as expected.

Why does this happen?

Comment: well if you redefine existing commands lots of curious things can happen. Are you absolutely sure that none of the other commands and inputs you will use in your document will rely on \d as it is meant to be?

Comment: It seems that `\a` is also predefined but redefining it `\renewcommand{\a}{\text{a}}` does not makes any error!!!

Comment: Unrelated:  using `\text{d}` to make an upright `d` is wrong, (1) it is a text `d` not math `d`, (2) it will be italic if the text outside of math is italic. Use `\mathrm{d}` instead.

Comment: Redefining short commands is very dangerous. When you'll be citing some Indian or Arabic author, you'll know why. Don't do it.

Comment: On page 49 of `hyperref` manual, there is a command `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{a}{\9036\241}` that produce `1EA1;LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DOT BELOW;...` and the error is because of this maybe.

Comment: @C.F.G The macro `\a` is needed in a `tabbing` environment to get accents. But I would advise against redefining commands without knowing what they do and hoping for the best.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I know it can be risky to redefine existing commands. However, in this case, I accept that risk. These are exercise sheets for my students where I will most certainly not use the original meaning of `\d`. The advantage in having a short command outweighs the risk. I might switch to `\dd{x}` from the `physics` package; did not know that, when I first used this macro ~15 years ago.

Comment: @egreg You are completely right and the comment is valuable for future reference. In this specific use case, there is no risk. I will never cite Indian or Arabic authors in a maths worksheet :)

Comment: @PhilippImhof the problem is, that you don't really know if you will use the original meaning, as the use can be hidden in other commands. And if I may say so: you are putting a bad example for your students here. What will you do if one of them asks for the tex source? Refuse to show it? Edit first?

Comment: @C.F.G Would you mind turning this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would show them and be honest about it. Teachers do not have to be perfect. :) As my students do not know nor use LaTeX, that is not going to happen very soon, though. This is not university level, but higher secondary education. But you are right. I will keep it in legacy documents, but use `physics` in new (and larger) documents.

Comment: physics isn't really loved, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470842/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know, thanks. What would you recommend? Simply use `\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}` ?

Comment: @daleif You are right. It is a legacy definition. In some newer documents, I use `\mathrm` instead of `\text`. I think, I did not yet know about (or pay attention to) those details ~15 years ago. And there was no tex.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: It is just something at least I'm very vocal about since we see of students and beginners use it wrongly. So better not have it in various questions to tempt them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert and I don't know the reason of error completely. You are not allowed to use (and probably redefine) the followings after of `hyperref` package:

- (backslash+ ` )
- `\^`
- `\~`
- `\"`
- `\r`
- `\v`
- `\.`
- `\c`
- `\=`
- `\b`
- `\d`

and the error is because of this maybe, as explained in comments and other answer it is better to use other command or you can use [`diffcoef`](https://ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) package instead. See for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/320360/90655) and [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319980/your-professional-rm-latex-experiences-that-saves-your-time-in-typesetting/320360#comment798722_320360).

Comment: The manual is describing how to define additional composites; that particular definition in the manual is there as example and is not part of the `PU` encoding, the re-definition of `\d` happens before that.

Comment: You are right but BTW in that file, there are another commands`\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PD1}{\@empty}{\textdotbelow}` and `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PD1}{\ }{\textdotbelow}` as i wrote, but my reference is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "additional" composites. Some composites are defined by default like the ones you quoted. However, those do not define `\d`: they are "exceptions" to what `\d` usually does, but the redefinition of `\d` is the one I posted in my answer.

Comment: Ok. i will edit my answer. Thank you.