# New package or class: way tho share it

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

My prime question is: is there a *proper* way/website to share a package or a class of our own?

If the question is too generic, I can try to refine it a little bit: what is the best way to get some alpha-testers for a new package or class before trying to share it on CTAN or similar?

**Context**

I write classes and packages from time to time.

Sometimes, we can find posts like [Alternatives to the physics package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471532/alternatives-to-the-physics-package) or [Physics replacement effort](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471563/physics-replacement-effort), where people discuss their own implementations that could be shared through a package or a class.

I doubt that the TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange is the right place to post a link to a GitHub repository or similar platform. Also, I'm not sure that we can send something directly to CTAN (or any other stuff) without having some alpha-testers.

Comment: This is the first time I'm psting a question. So please tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm out of the scope.

Comment: You might propose them to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/upload/).

Comment: You could post it at [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (and perhaps advertise your question in the chat room of this site). The author of the  `tikzducks` apparently did that too: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/171782

Comment: I don't see why you can't share your package on github/gitlab/etc... to serve your purpose. I actually find it useful: for example, I use europecv2013 class, which is not on CTAN, but by cloning the repo in my texmf folder, I only need to `git pull` to get the latest updates.
On the other side, I don't think that sharing the github repo link in a question  here on TeX.SE may be appropriate, just to let people knwo that it exists.
But you can always look for questions that *may be answered* by your package, and provide your input.

Answer (score 2):

Here follows a summary based on the comments that I received. I will edit it if I receive more answers.

**Step 1: GitHub**

Post on GitHub: easy to share, tracking.
People can simply `git pull` the repository in their local LaTeX distribution to get the latest updates.

**Step 2: answer/question on TeX.SE**

Try to find questions for which your class or package could be helpful.
This is a way to get alpha-testers who need to solve a specific issue.

You could also share the GitHub link by posting a question. To be confirmed by moderators.

**Step 3: CTAN**

The last step is to post your package/class on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/upload/). This is the best way to distribute your package/class to all LaTeX users.