# Upload a self-made package into a repository

Tags: graphics, pdftex, packages

I made a latex package for these little Ozobot-robots. The main idea is that they follow a line. You can program them to control the behavior.

A fast Internet search gave me no clue how to upload a package and how to package a package ( :-) ). Is there ONE repository or are there many for all these latex-distributions?

The package relies on ready made pdf-images. Is this a problem? Can I include these images into the package?

Comment: I think that your first question could find an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510926/new-package-or-class-way-tho-share-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctan won't mind the pdf files but texlive has stronger open source rules and normally likes to have the source for any pdfs (but if they are really images in pdf format not tex-generated from tikz or whatever, that can be waived). Otherwise all you need to do is zip up the `.sty` and a `README.txt` and use the ctan upload form with instructions here:

https://ctan.org/help/upload-pkg

Comment: thank you David, I'll try. The pdf-images are really simple. maybe I can include the rendering in tikz and they need not to be pre-rendered.